# jQuery stop scrolling when img fixed reach the footer

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scroll

I can't find how to stop an image fixed on top of the footer div when you scroll on the bottom of the page.

I tried to calculate the footer height to remove it from the `window.height` to force scrolling stop at that point.

`.footer-arrow` is my fixed image.

The code below does this semi-successfully:

```
$(function() {
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    var footHeight = $('#footer').offset().top;
    var height = (($(window).height()) - footHeight);
    // if ($(document).height() - footHeight <= ($(window).height() + $(window).scrollTop()))
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > footHeight) {
      $('.footer-arrow').css({
        position: 'fixed',
        bottom: 20
      });
    } else {
      $('.footer-arrow').addClass('fixed');
      $('.footer-arrow').css({
        position: 'fixed',
        bottom: 140,
      });
    }
  })
});
```

Comment: Could you include your html please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to stop your image at the top of footer, you shouldn't check condition `$(this).scrollTop() > footHeight`. Instead, you should check if bottom of image reaches to the top of footer

```
var elementOffset = $('#footer').offset().top;
var footerTop = (elementOffset - $(window).scrollTop());
if(imageBottom > footerTop ){ /* image is fixed */ } else { /* image keep image above footer */ }
```

What is "imageBottom" depends on what's the height of your image and how long is its distance from the top of the window.

I hope it helps.

**Update**

Based on your jsfiddle, it should work:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    var elementOffset = $('#footer').offset().top;
    var footerTop = (elementOffset - $(window).scrollTop());
    if(footerTop > ($(window).height() - 20)) {
      $('.footer-arrow').css({
        position: 'fixed',
        bottom: 20
        });
      }
      //debugger;
    if( footerTop < ($(window).height() - 20) ){
        $('.footer-arrow').addClass('fixed');
          $('.footer-arrow').css({
            position: 'fixed',
            bottom: ($(window).height() - footerTop),
        });
    }
})
```

Comment: Thank you for your help Alireza, I try something else according to what you told me but it doesn't work eather : https://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=D4i5dfqSLc

Comment: @katalinanadasi I updated my answer. It should work for you.

Comment: That works very fine indeed. That's awesome @alireza kasaaian, thank you very much !

Comment: @katalinanadasi you are welcome. I'll be glad if you accept my answer :)